# Void method in class c#

Tags: c#, class, methods, void

I have a problem with calling a method void for a string.

I've created a class:

```
    public string SendData(string val1){ return val1; }

    public void RecoverBirth()
    {
        clsConnectionClass conn = new clsConnectionClass();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from birthday";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                SendData(dr[1].ToString() + " " + dr[2].ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I try to retrieve the data from the class

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _test = new Test();
    string Result = _test.RecoverBirth();
}
```

This error occurs:

> Can't convert method "void" to "string"

I need RecoverBirth method to be Void not "string", because it has a lot of different cycle and not everything return something, and if I declare it as string I have to use a lot of return null.

Is there a (better) way to do this?

Comment: public void DoSome() in class Test does not return anything. So, either it needs to be  public string DoSome(), or you need to call it as just _test.DoSome() without setting string Result = ...

Comment: Simplest: Change return type of `DoSome()` to string. Or pass a string by `out` argument to `DoSome()` and then assign the value to it inside function. You can learn more on `out` keyword in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

Comment: Ok I should I've said that I need that method to be Void not "string", that's why I pass at the end that to the public string and I don't declare it from the beginning

Comment: Why do you need it to be `void`?

Comment: Because it contains a lot of functions that don't return anything. Otherwise I have to declare "return null" everywhere else

Comment: Well, I think it's time for a major round of code and design reviews. If you're dealing with issues like this, your design is probably extremely leaky. Fix the design, and you'll avoid having methods that always return null except for that one case where they don't.

Comment: It doesn't matter what functions or cycles the method contains and whether these contained methods return anything. It only matters whether or not the method itself must logically return something. Looking at your `RecoverBirth` it is not clear if it must return something or it is intended to change internal state of things. Have a think about it and declare it as `void` or `string` based on that and that alone.

Answer (score 1):

The `void` keyword in the `C#` language indicates that a method returns nothing.

You should use the `return` keyword which means that a method returns only one value. What type of return value of the method you should specify at signature of the method. For example:

```
public string MethodA(bool isItReally)
```

In the above code return value is type of `string`.

So, you should correct the method like that:
Your updated code:

```
class Test
{
    public string RecoverBirth()
    {
        clsConnectionClass conn = new clsConnectionClass();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from birthday";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string colValue;
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {                    
                 colValue= dr[1].ToString() + " " + dr[2].ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        return colValue;
    }
}
```

It is not possible to assign to a `string` variable a value of `void` method as 
`void` method returns nothing.

Comment: Not sure why people are upvoting this as it won't compile and won't do anything sensible.

Comment: And anyway I need DoSome() to be void not string

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio please see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, so how should I do that without fill all my method with result = null if I declare that as string?

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio Why do you need to assign to result a null value? give full code to decide how we can try to solve the problem

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio please see my updated answer

Comment: I know that it works like this but this is just a part of the code, it is very long and I have to use return "colValue" everywhere otherwise it wouldn't work, that's why I was trying to find something better

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio sure it is. It is a rule of programming:). You should keep to this rules

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test
{  

    public string StringValue { get; set;}

    public void DoSome()
    {
        while(some code here)
        {
            //something here
            //set StringValue to what you like
            this.StringValue = "this is now the text";
        }          
    }
}
```

and then

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = new Test();
    test.DoSome();
    var result = test.StringValue;
}
```

Comment: As I said I need that method to be void

Comment: could you explain more... do you need the value result in my example.

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio something like that?, Updated

Comment: The problem is that this execute the string only once, but the "while" is to read and pass a lot of strings. With this in the button_click I just read the last string passed.
I need this to be void because DoSome() has a lot of functions and not everything return something, otherwise I have to add a lot of return null

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio if my updated answer is still not what you are looking for then... i think its best you add your while logic code to the question... as it seems to be hanging off that then...

Comment: Ok maybe this little will help you figure out what I'm trying to do: 
    class Birthday
    {
        public string SendResult(string val1){ return val1; }

        public void RecovBirth()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Birth";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    SendResult(dr[1].ToString() + " " + dr[2].ToString() + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }

    }

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio well in that case i would highly suggest you have a look http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand

Answer (score 0):

You better start with basic ... It's very `basic` things in programming dude..

```
class Test
{
    public string s1(string val) { return val; }

    public string DoSome()
    {
        while(some code here)
            {
            s1(result1 + result2);
        } 
        //Must return string to get as string
       return someVariableOfString;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want your method to be of `void` return type then pass parameter by reference with `out` keyword to the method, and in this case method can directly change the reference value and so you can get the new value back in 'calling' code.

You can learn more on `out` in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

```
public void DoSome(out string result)
{
     //Do whatever stuff you want and assign the new value(string in your case) to the parameter  

     result = "My new string after some processing.";
}
```

Calling:

```
string result;
DoSomething(out result); //After successful execution of this line `result` will have newly assigned string value from within the function
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: It's the same as "string", because DoSome() has a lot of functions,  and not everything return something, otherwise I have to add a lot of return null

Answer (score 0):

If you need your method to return `void`, you could use the `out` keyword to pass in your result as a reference variable, like this:

```
class Test
{
    public string SendData(string val1){ return val1; }

    public void RecoverBirth(out string result)
    {
        clsConnectionClass conn = new clsConnectionClass();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from birthday";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result += SendData(dr[1].ToString() + " " + dr[2].ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your call:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _test = new Test();
    string result = null;
    _test.RecoverBirth(out result);
}
```

Comment: It's the same as "string", because DoSome() has a lot of functions,  and not everything return something, otherwise I have to add a lot of return null

Comment: With this code you won't have to add a lot of `return null`. Just don't touch `result` and it will behave as usual!

Comment: Error in class Test: "Parameter out 'result' has to be assigned before the control leave the current method".

Comment: Nope, same problem in the class. If I add result = "smthg" to other parts of the method it works, but it is the same as declare DoSome as string

Comment: Have you seen my latest edit? You can set the result to another string, and set `result` from that string at the end of your function. You might need to update your answer with more information as people (including me) seem to have a hard time understanding your problem... This is not the same as declaring `DoSome` as `string`.

Comment: I've made an edit to my code to reflect your question. As others have stated, your problem is quite weird and could use a round of reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the nagging doubts about a design where something like this makes sense... you could use an argument to emit whatever output necessary. For example:

```
public void DoSomething(Action<string> someAction = null)
{
  // When it's time to emit a result, just do
  if (someAction != null) someAction("Hello world!");
}
```

Which you can then call as

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
DoSomething(s => sb.AppendLine(s));
```

If you're calling from a place that doesn't care about the "return value", you can just omit the argument:

```
DoSomething();
```

But *seriously*, your design needs lots of work if you have to do something like this. Also, there's nothing wrong with `return null` - it's hard to see why that would be an issue in your code. Just replace all those `return;` with `return null;` or something. But it seems like your method simply does way too many things if you care about the distinction.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that this was the time for design review. I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do this